# How to have an const iterator out of non const vector in c++98

Tags: vector, stl, iterator, constants, c++98

I am writing a function that can't be declared const because it uses an iterator on one of its attributes, and I don't know how to extract a const iterator out of a non const vector without using cbegin() and cend(). My compiler doesn't recognize this functions.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re declaring the function `const` then your vector member will *also* be `const`, and `begin()` and `end()` will consequently return `const_iterator`s. So you’re fine.

But in general you can always force a `const_iterator` by casting a `std::vector<T>` instance to `std::vector<T> const&`.

Comment: you're right, it is working, while any cast required. But by cast de you mean (const vector<MyType>) or const_cast<const vector<MyType>>(MyVector). I just tried the const_cast and it is not working. I think const_cast is just to make a const variable non const and not making a non const variable const.

Comment: @user2482582 Since you’re changing the `const`ness, `const_cast` is the way to go. In fact, the other, C-style, cast should be completely taboo in your code. (But like I said, in *your situation*, no cast at all is required.)